# Create a specific Web Scraper

Tags: python, html, for-loop, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am making the effort to learn to scrape in Python and in this case my idea is to make a tool that obtains data from a web page. I have a problem in proposing the "for" to go through the page and collect the data of each box (item) as they are:

- IDoffer
- List
- Title
- Location
- content
- phone

It is not a task, it is my own initiative but I am not moving forward for which I thank you for your help.

Here is what I have of code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL_BASE = "https://www.milanuncios.com/ofertas-de-empleo-en-madrid/?dias=3&demanda=n&pagina="
MAX_PAGES = 2
counter = 0

for i in range(0, MAX_PAGES):

    #Building the URL
    if i > 0:
        url = "%s%d" % (URL_BASE, i)
    else:
        url = URL_BASE

    #We make the request to the web
    req = requests.get(url)
    
    #We check that the request returns a Status Code = 200
    statusCode = req.status_code
    if statusCode == 200:

        #We pass the HTML content of the web to a BeautifulSoup () object
        html = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

        #We get all the divs where the inputs are
        entradas_IDoffer = html.find_all('div', {'class': 'aditem-header'})
        
        #We go through all the inputs and extract info
        for entrada1 in entradas_IDoffer:
            
            #THIS ARE SOME ATTEMPS
            #Title = entrada.find('div', {'class': 'aditem-detail-title'}).getText()
            #location = entrada.find('div', {'class': 'list-location-region'}).getText()
            #content = entrada.find('div', {'class': 'tx'}).getText()
            #phone = entrada.find('div', {'class': 'telefonos'}).getText()
        
            #Offer Title
            entradas_Title = html.find_all('div', {'class': 'aditem-detail'})
            for entrada2 in entradas_Title:
                counter += 1
                Title = entrada2.find('a', {'class': 'aditem-detail-title'}).getText()
                
            counter += 1
            IDoffer = entrada1.find('div', {'class': 'x5'}).getText()
                    
                    

        #Location
        #entradas_location = html.find_all('div', {'class': 'aditem-detail'})
        #for entrada4 in entradas_location:
        #    counter += 1
        #    location = entrada4.find('div', {'class': 'list-location-region'}).getText()

                    #Offer content
                    #entradas_content = html.find_all('div', {'class': 'aditem-detail'})
                    #for entrada3 in entradas_content:
                     #   counter += 1
                      #  content = entrada3.find('div', {'class': 'tx'}).getText()

            print("%d - %s  \n%s\n%s" % (counter, IDoffer.strip(),url,Title))

    else:
        try:
            r = requests.head(req)
            print(r.status_code)

        except requests.ConnectionError:
            print("failed to connect")
        break
        #If the page no longer exists and it gives me a 400
```

Comment: In this line `for input2 in input_Title` , what is `input_Title`? You never define it anywhere.

Comment: @SimonR Thank you for your observation, I've already corrected the code. It was a translation issue. Now you can continue helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct entradas_IDoffer,

```
entradas_IDoffer = html.find_all("div", class_="aditem CardTestABClass")
```

Title is located under "a" tag not "div"

```
title = entrada.find("a", class_="aditem-detail-title").text.strip()
location = entrada.find("div", class_="list-location-region").text.strip()
content = entrada.find("div", class_="tx").text.strip()
```

do like this for other data

they might be loading Phone number with javascript so you may not able to get that with bs4, you can get that using selenium.

You wrote very lengthy code to loop through multiple pages, just do this to go through page 1 and 2 using range. Put url in formatted string.

```
for page in range(1, 3):
    url =  f'https://www.milanuncios.com/ofertas-de-empleo-en-madrid/?dias=3&demanda=n&pagina={page}'
```

Full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in range(1, 5):
    url =  f'https://www.milanuncios.com/ofertas-de-empleo-en-madrid/?dias=3&demanda=n&pagina={page}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    entradas_IDoffer = soup.find_all("div", class_="aditem CardTestABClass")

    for entrada in entradas_IDoffer:
        title = entrada.find("a", class_="aditem-detail-title").text.strip()
        ID = entrada.find("div", class_="x5").text.strip()
        location = entrada.find("div", class_="list-location-region").text.strip()
        content = entrada.find("div", class_="tx").text.strip()
        
        print(title, ID, location, content)
```

Comment: As you said, it seems to be easier with Selenium but I still having trouble proposing the for-loop. If I use yours, I only get the first record of each page, it doesn't crawl each of the whole pages. Any suggestions?

Comment: Full code updated. It will go through first 4 pages, you can change number of pages in range.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Best wishes for your 2021!!

Comment: Have a wonderful 2021!! Code updated a bit. I used "page" two times, once for page number and one as variable, it won't cause any problem but Its not a good practice.